# How can i run a shell script with administrator privileges within SwiftUI using osascript

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

I’m trying to make a simple macOS App which runs a shell script **with administrator privileges** when a specific button is pressed. To run the shell script in terminal i successfully tested this command:

*osascript -e 'do shell script "/Users/andreas/checkertool.sh" with administrator privileges'*

Unfortunately i'm not able to execute this command when pressing the button. Following error message appears:

*0:2: execution error: The variable „do“ is not defined. (-2753)*

This is what my code looks like so far. Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var script = "/Users/andreas/checkertool.sh"
    @State var isRunning = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Checker Tool")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    let process = Process()
                    process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
                    process.arguments = ["-e", "do", "shell script", "/Users/andreas/checkertool.sh", "with administrator privileges"]
                    process.launch()
                    process.waitUntilExit()
                }) {
                    Text("Check")
                }.disabled(isRunning)
                    .padding(.trailing)
            }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: *do shell script* is **one** expression. Apart from that be aware that you cannot run shell scripts / AppleScripts in a sandboxed app via Process.

Comment: SwiftUI is designed to separate the UI from an application's logic. A better design is to move the calling of the script to another class and use the [Combine Framework](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/722/) to react on the changing of a value when the user interacts with your UI.
Ideally, if you want to call a privileged action, you would create a separate process via an XPC helper to perform the action on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct terminal command should be as (if you use specific shell inside script then `sh` should be replaced correspondingly, say `bash`)

> $ osascript -e 'do shell script "sh /Users/andreas/checkertool.sh"
>   with administrator privileges'

so your arguments should be as follow:

```
process.arguments = ["-e", "do shell script \"sh /Users/andreas/checkertool.sh\" with administrator privileges"]
```

P.S. assuming you do this w/o sandbox, because I have doubts it would allow this.

Comment: Asperi,

thanks for the fast reply. the "do shell script" command is working properly now. However following error message appears:

0:80: execution error: The username or password of the administrator is wrong. (-60005)

Is there a way to force an authentication window to pop up?

Best, Andreas

Comment: As I commented this is due to sandbox settings. To use this you have to disable sandbox in your app. If sandbox is required then you can't use this feature.

Comment: How can i disaple the sandbox settings?

Comment: Find file with `.entitlements` extension in your project and set `NO` for `App Sandbox` row.